# Python scraping in virustotal.com

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I want to get malware hashes from https://www.virustotal.com/gui/user/thor/comments this comments and save to text file or database.After that in every 5 minutes refreshes itself and automatically adds new hashes to text file or database.
i tried it with beautifulsoup and request libs but this comments don't have tag(a, div etc.) and class because comment section works on javascript.

How can i scrape this hashes from comments?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: you will facing an trouble with that site since it's using `XHR` which load `JS` after load the page. am working for solution right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  which actually renders the webpage and not an html parser like beautifulsoup.